# getInitialProps is called on front end in nextjs

Tags: authentication, next.js, server-side-rendering, auth0

I have code for user fetch from the session in `_app.tsx`.

```
MyApp.getInitialProps = async ({ ctx }: any) => {
  const { req, res } = ctx;

  const session = auth0.getSession(req, res)
  return { user: session?.user } 

}
```

Problem is, that `getInitialProps` is sometimes called on client-side. I don`t understand why? Documentation says:

```
`getInitialProps enables server-side rendering in a page and allows you to do initial data population, which means sending the page with the data already populated from the server. This is especially useful for SEO.
```

https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/getInitialProps

What is wrong? Why is my function called on client-side?

In case I am wrong, how can I fetch user session data from server on server side?

Comment: yes because getInitialProps is same as getServerSideProps it will call every request but not in the client side but in the server side.

Comment: If you read on further, you'll also notice the following: _"For the initial page load, `getInitialProps` will run on the server only. `getInitialProps` will then run on the client when navigating to a different route via the `next/link` component or by using `next/router`"_. Use [`getServerSideProps`](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#getserversideprops-server-side-rendering) instead to have it called on the server only.

Answer (score 1):

Since `getInitialProps` called on client and server, you have to write authentication logic for both cases. To get the session on client use `useUser` hook, on server use `getSession`

```
import { useUser } from '@auth0/nextjs-auth0';

let user;
if (typeof window === 'undefined'){
   const session=auth0.getSession(req,res)
   console.log("check session to get user",session)
   user=session.user
} else {
     const data = useUser()
     user=data.user
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The [link](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/getInitialProps) you shared explains you need to use `getServerSideProps` instead of `getInitialProps` for Next.js version > 9.3.